# Почему происходит смена формата цвета?

Tags: dom, javascript-events

Есть массив с цветами в формате hex, есть функция вызывающая случайный цвет(getRandomArrayElement). Почему при таком коде по клику на элемент меняется формат с hex на rgb?

Код функции:

```
var changeElementColor = function () {
elementColor.style.backgroundColor = getRandomArrayElement(ELEMENT_COLORS);
document.getElementsByName('element-color')[0].value = 
elementColor.style.backgroundColor;
};
```

Код случайного элемента

```
var getRandomArrayElement = function (arr) {
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
return arr[index];
};
```

Comment: Ваше определение  `массив формата HEX` подразумевает символ `#` перед числом?

Comment: Да, именно так.